# Can Chat Stack Overflow have a different icon?

Tags: feature-request, chat, favicon

It's just a minor thing. So you know when you pin a tab in Firefox or Chrome, it removes the title from the tab, right? Or when you have so many tabs opened, it does requires time to distinguish between the both.

**I wonder if it would be nice if there is a slight difference in the icons between the normal Stack Overflow and the chat room**.

A few easy suggestions:

- Batch process icons and add a "c" badge to a corner.
- Tint icons in another color like the meta icons.
- Update certain icons when the sites are having design changes to minimize work.

Comment: [Different favicon for chat window/tab](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/85146)

Comment: The icon could show activity since the last visit ... an empty "stack" with no activity, one message adds the first item, second message (or other user) the second etc.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider This is a good design feature! +1

Comment: @GeraldSchneider They would already need to create 100 icons, now multiply that by 5. Great idea but a tad impractical :)

Comment: Why 100 icons though? Aren’t there just three chat networks? Chat.SO, Chat.SE, and Chat.Meta.SE. That’s just three icons, no?

Comment: @poke All the other StackExchange sites have their own chat.

Comment: @Xufox They don’t. It’s all [the same chat network](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=all&sort=active). The view is just usually filtered by site, which makes them appear separate.

Comment: Good luck getting them to spend time on their "third place". It doesn't generate revenue and is seen more as a hobbyist place than an actual contributor to the exchange.

Comment: @poke Each chat site still has the icon from the site. If each site needs a distinguishing icon for the chat, that still are around 100 icons.

Comment: How about one where the icon is split in half vertically? Subtle yet effective.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider: don't you want to cache the favicon.ico?